# sql agent job notification email without configuring database mail

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

Is there any way to send sql agent job notification email without configuring Database Mail?

Currently I am using Database Mail but due to security concern, i need to disable Database Mail feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily invoke a Powershell script:
(Change the FromEmailAddress, ToEmailAddress and SmtpClient information)

```
$computerName = gc env:computername
$emailFrom = $computerName + “<EmailFromAddress>.com”
$emailTo = "<EmailToAddress>.com"
$subject = "Testing email"
$emailBody = "This is an example of sending email via Powershell"
$message = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $emailbody)
$message.Priority = "HIGH"
$smtpServer = "<YourSmtpServer>.com"
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott for the reply, I am totally unfamiliar with Powershell, can you please also suggest how can i get the JOB NAME,DURATION,STATUS and MESSAGE of the last run step inside this Powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use Database Mail, one of the options for you is to invoke VBScripts similar to this:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type     = 2 'text
stream.Position = 0
stream.Charset  = "utf-8"
Set Str = WScript.Arguments 
For I = 0 to Str.Count - 1
   res = Str(I)
Next
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
strComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork") 
Const ForReading = 1 
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = "WARNING " & strComputerName & " " & objNet.UserDomain & "." & objNet.UserName 
objMessage.From = "<FromE-Mail>" 

objMessage.to="<ToUserE-Mail>"

objMessage.TextBody = "The task" & databaseName & " " & " failed on computer " & strComputerName & ". Date and time: " & Now() & vbCrLF & vbCrLf & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & "Message: "  &res
'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP  
'server.Normally you will only change the server name or IP. 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2  
'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "YourSMTPServer" 
'Server port number(typically 25) 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
'objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 2
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "domain\user"
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "<password>"
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update 
objMessage.Send 
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objMessage = Nothing 
stream.Close
```